# Set Default value for dynamic select list

Tags: apex, visualforce

How can we set a default value for selectoption.

I have a custom setting which list several languages and on VF we have to display a all values from custom setting making a default value based on user's language.

e.g.:  if Users default language is French, select option on Vf should display FR.

Comment: e.g.:  if Users default language is French, select option on Vf should display FR.

 <apex:selectList label="Language" id="language" value="Language" size="1" style="width:100px;" rendered="{!!active}" required="true" multiselect="false" >                                  
       <apex:selectOptions value="{!usrRec.Language2}"    />
 </apex:selectList>

Answer (score 4):

You just get userinfo and put it inside selectList variable.

An example would look like this

//controller

```
Public List<SelectOption> langs {get; set;}
Public String userlang {get; set;}
public myController(){
    langs = new List<SelectOption>();
    langs.add(new SelectOption('en', 'EN'));
    langs.add(new SelectOption('fr', 'FR'));
    langs.add(new SelectOption('tr', 'TR'));
    userlang = UserInfo.getLocale().substringBefore('_'); //this will return user's langauge.

}
```

//vf page

```
    <apex:selectList value="{!userlang}" size="1">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!langs}"/>
    </apex:selectList>
```

Comment: That helped a lot.. thanks for your valuable suggestion.